# SEGFAULT on strcpy

Tags: c

i have a function that starts as

```
void findErrors(int lineIndex){
  char *line;
  strcpy(line, lines[lineIndex]);
```

then calls another functions that starts as

```
void fixErrors(int lineIndex, char *word){
  char *line;
  strcpy(line, lines[lineIndex]);
```

the first function works but i get a segfault when it calls the second function. lineIndex is the same for both words and findErrors does not call the lines array except in strcpy(). Why is this happening? is this a bad way to use the function and i'm simply getting lucky on the first function? The problem goes away if I change the line in fixErrors from

```
char *line;
```

to

```
char line[255];
```

but i'd rather not have a possibility of another segfault on a huge line. i guess i could also

```
char *line = malloc(strlen(lines[lineIndex])+1)
```

but i'm really curios why the first way doesn't work.

Comment: `char *line = malloc(strlen(lines[lineIndex]))` won't suffice, you need one character more because of the end null character.

Comment: You have an uninitialized pointer, and using uninitialized variables including pointers has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `is this a bad way to use the function and i'm simply getting lucky on the first function`...yes, mostly.

Comment: *malloc (strlen (x))* is practically *always* wrong without a "+1" and should be a compiler check pattern..... As long as it isn't, any programmer should check ;) A safer thing to do is *strdup(x)*

Comment: @Sourav I don't consider having a wrong program working to be luck. I would prefer my wrong programs never work. It's often a pain to find a glitch when it does not systematically prevent the program from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void findErrors(int lineIndex){
  char *line;
  strcpy(line, lines[lineIndex]);
//^ this is undefined behaviour.
```

At that point `line` is not initialized and strcopying something to a non initialized pointer results in undefined behaviour, usually a segfault.

But if by chance `line` points to some valid memory, the program may not crash and it may look as if it works. It's undefined behaviour.

Case where it works:

```
void findErrors(int lineIndex){
  char line[255];
  strcpy(line, lines[lineIndex]);
```

Here `line` points to a buffer of length 255. You can `strcpy` to this buffer without problems as long as the length of the source string is smaller than 254.

Why "smaller than 254" and not 255 ?

Because we need one more char for the zero terminator.